# Как заставить стандартные «хлебные крошки» выводить не первую категорию, а основную в woocommerce?

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, breadcrumbs

Суть в том что стандартные крошки woocommerce прекрасно работают только если товар находится в одной категории. Если же товар находится в нескольких категориях, то крошки выводят не основную категорию (назначенную в админке) а первую. 
Собственно вопрос в том как заставить стандартные крошки выводить не первую категорию, а основную.

Если выводить крошки с помощью yoast, то они выводят как раз правильно, но возникает лишний элемент /товары/ т.е. получается Главная/товары/рубрика/название-товара. Как то можно убрать /товары/ что то не соображу как это сделать. Google и Yandex молчат((

Кто нибудь решал такой вопрос??

Answer (score 0):

SEO -> Дополнительно -> Постоянные ссылки -> 
"Strip the category base (usually /category/) from the category URL" в положение Remove.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Если нет пункта меню Дополнительно, то SEO->Dashboard->Features->Advanced Setting->Enabled.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: не это не помогает я уже пробовал

Comment: У меня-то работает. Покажите реальные ссылки, можно без домена. Что есть и что надо.

Comment: Посмотрите fleurenvy.ru

Comment: не увидел у вас вообще "хлебных крошек", речь как раз о них, а не url

Comment: я вот про это http://joxi.ru/EA44npXCg1y1Ab

Comment: кстати заметил на вашем сайте ошибочку или это специально? http://joxi.ru/DrlB7ObUpo1o2P

Comment: Я вернусь, гляну про крошки. На сайте ошибка, спасибо. Я с ним не заморачивался особо. Какой браузер? В Хроме ок.

Comment: как раз у меня в Chome и в Yandex тоже, в Explorer и Edge  ок, в остальных не смотрел

Comment: Да ну, в Хроме все ок, на всех разрешениях - вот снимок с компа: http://take.ms/CQr77

Comment: Я понял в чем прикол)) перезагрузи Ctrl+F5

Comment: вот https://youtu.be/phUgHs0MCiM         я просто привык перезагружать Ctrl+F5 (глупая привычка) поэтому и видел постоянно, если перезагрузить обычным способом, то все ok

Comment: Никаких приколов и после ctrl+f5, и после ctlr+h, и сбрасывания wp super cache, и сбрасывания кеша cloudflare. Возможно, у вас какое-то расширение в Хроме.

Comment: Ads Killer, вижу, грузится

Comment: да нет ни каких расширений особо нет

Comment: Ads Killer отключил все равно так же

Comment: Вопрос, конечно, ни о чем. Но все же: если у меня работает, как задумано, а у вас не работает, и сервер один - то проблема, очевидно, у вас.

Comment: Какое разрешение экрана? Что в инспекторе браузера? Почему фон меньше текста?

Comment: действительно)) просто хотел помочь если ошибка возникает у меня, значит она может возникнуть у любого пользователя, ну да ладно.

Comment: Спасибо, конечно. Но из практики: я нечто подобное слышал от многих заказчиков: "сделайте, чтобы у меня работало!" А это сделать нельзя, потому что все криво на его конкретной системе. Приходилось, например, посылать считать пиксели на экране, потом возвращаться. По факту - возвращались с извинениями. Я для себя вывел: 95% за то, что все правильно, если у меня работает. Но за замечание лично вам - все равно спасибо.