# Можно ли закомментировать часть кода плагина yoast?

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

Собственно вопрос вытекает из этого [Как заставить стандартные «хлебные крошки» выводить не первую категорию, а основную в woocommerce?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/647018/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B4%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%82%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5-%D1%85%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%B1%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5-%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%88%D0%BA%D0%B8-%D0%B2%D1%8B%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BD%D0%B5-%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B2%D1%83%D1%8E-%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%B3%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%8E-%D0%B0-%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B2)
нашел в коде плагина yoast часть кода которая отвечает за вывод ссылки ***/товары/*** если ее закомментировать, то все работает как надо. Собственно вопрос в том как закомментировать этот код? В код самого плагина лезть не охота т.к. после каждого обновления придется делать тоже самое. Возможно ли сделать это например через function.php?

Дополнение. Возможно я не правильно выразился. Под словом закомментировать я имел ввиду, возможно ли с помощью хука изменить часть кода плагина? Например заменить на свой кусок кода или деактивировать, или ...........

Вот часть кода файла class-breadcrumbs.php

```
private function prepare_links() {
    if ( ! is_array( $this->crumbs ) || $this->crumbs === array() ) {
        return;
    }

    foreach ( $this->crumbs as $i => $crumb ) {
        // Keep pre-set url/text combis.
        $link_info = $crumb;

        if ( isset( $crumb['id'] ) ) {
            $link_info = $this->get_link_info_for_id( $crumb['id'] );
        }
        if ( isset( $crumb['term'] ) ) {
            $link_info = $this->get_link_info_for_term( $crumb['term'] );
        }
        // Эта часть кода выводит не нужную мне ссылку
        if ( isset( $crumb['ptarchive'] ) ) {
            $link_info = $this->get_link_info_for_ptarchive( $crumb['ptarchive'] );
        }
        // конец
        $this->links[] = $this->crumb_to_link( $link_info, $i );
    }
}
```

Comment: Как можно закомментировать код, не трогая кода)))

Comment: ну например можно же убрать ссылку на главную в стандартных крошках woocommerce не трогая самого кода, с помощью сниппета

Comment: Покажите кусок кода, который надо исправить.

Comment: И, собственно, - а вы что, крошки выводите с помощью функции yoast?  В первом вопросе звучало "стандартные крошки woocommerce"

Comment: просто это единственные крошки которые выводят цепочку именно так как нужно, т.е. берется именно основная категория, а не первая.

Comment: Если можете помочь со стандартными крошками woocommerce, что бы вывод цепочки был так как нужно, буду признателен, это даже лучше чем использовать плагин

Comment: Я нашел ответ, что и как делать со стандартными крошками в woo. Но лучше создать новый вопрос конкретно на эту тему, что-то вроде "Как править крошки в woo", потому что люди вряд ли смогут найти для себя ответ вот по такому заголовку вопроса, как сейчас.

Comment: а этот не подойдет? http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/647018/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B4%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%82%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5-%D1%85%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%B1%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5-%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%88%D0%BA%D0%B8-%D0%B2%D1%8B%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BD%D0%B5-%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B2%D1%83%D1%8E-%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%B3%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%8E-%D0%B0-%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B2 ,но не принципиально могу и новую создать

Comment: вот такая формулировка возможна http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/647496/%D0%9D%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B9%D0%BA%D0%B0-%D1%85%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%B1%D0%BD%D1%8B%D1%85-%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%88%D0%B5%D0%BA-woocommerce