# Настройка хлебных крошек WooCommerce

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

Cтандартные крошки WooCommerce прекрасно работают, только если товар находится в одной категории. Если же товар находится в нескольких категориях, то крошки выводят не основную категорию (назначенную в админке), а первую. Собственно, вопрос в том, как заставить стандартные крошки выводить не первую категорию, а основную.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В WooCommerce есть шаблон вывода хлебных крошек. Расположен он тут: `wp-content/plugins/woocommerce/templates/global/breadcrumb.php`. Этот файл надо скопировать в `wp-content/themes/моя-тема/woocommerce/breadcrumb.php` и отредактировать. Сам код в `breadcrumps.php` очень простой:

```
<?php

if ( ! defined( 'ABSPATH' ) ) {
    exit;
}

if ( ! empty( $breadcrumb ) ) {

    echo $wrap_before;

    foreach ( $breadcrumb as $key => $crumb ) {

        echo $before;

        if ( ! empty( $crumb[1] ) && sizeof( $breadcrumb ) !== $key + 1 ) {
            echo '<a href="' . esc_url( $crumb[1] ) . '">' . esc_html( $crumb[0] ) . '</a>';
        } else {
            echo esc_html( $crumb[0] );
        }

        echo $after;

        if ( sizeof( $breadcrumb ) !== $key + 1 ) {
            echo $delimiter;
        }

    }

    echo $wrap_after;

}
```

Однако в самом WooCommerce отсутствуют такие понятия, как основная (или первичная категория). Возможность задания первичной категории для товара появляется только после установки Yoast SEO. Вывод "хлебных крошек" в стиле yoast с указанием первичной категории нужно делать с помощью функции `yoast_breadcrumps()`. При этом в коде `breadcrumb.php` надо удалить или закомментировать имеющееся и добавить вызов `yoast_breadcrumps()`:

```
<?php

if ( ! defined( 'ABSPATH' ) ) {
    exit;
}

if ( ! empty( $breadcrumb ) ) {
/*
    echo $wrap_before;

    foreach ( $breadcrumb as $key => $crumb ) {

        echo $before;

        if ( ! empty( $crumb[1] ) && sizeof( $breadcrumb ) !== $key + 1 ) {
            echo '<a href="' . esc_url( $crumb[1] ) . '">' . esc_html( $crumb[0] ) . '</a>';
        } else {
            echo esc_html( $crumb[0] );
        }

        echo $after;

        if ( sizeof( $breadcrumb ) !== $key + 1 ) {
            echo $delimiter;
        }

    }

    echo $wrap_after;
*/

    if ( function_exists('yoast_breadcrumb') ) {
        $ybc = yoast_breadcrumb('<p id="breadcrumbs">','</p>', false);
        $arr = explode('»', $ybc);
        $ybc = $arr[0] . '»' . $arr[2];
        echo $ybc;
    }

}
```

Третий параметр в `yoast_breadcrumps()` отвечает за вывод на экран или возврат строки. Мы ставим его в false и получаем строку хлебных крошек $ybc. До вывода на экран эту строку можно обработать, что мы и делаем, вычленяя из нее ненужную информацию.

Пример вывода до вырезания ненужной информации:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Здесь произведен вывод "стандартных" "хлебных крошек" WooCommerce (верхняя строка) и "крошек" от yoast (нижняя строка). Ненужную информацию в нижней строке (например,  » Товары » ) можно вырезать строковыми функциями php.

Пример вывода после вырезания ненужной информации:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Это можно сделать и другими способами, хотя так наверно правильней. Вопрос который меня мучает как раз в том, как вырезать эту самую не нужную информацию (например /товары/)?

Comment: Так - абсолютно правильно, потому что обновляемо. Я не совсем понимаю, что надо вырезать. Если вот это - » Товары », то ок, накидаю код.

Comment: да именно это - » Товары »

Comment: Дополнил ответ.

Comment: так почему то не работает, http://joxi.ru/zAN6p5at4MY6A9

Comment: Ну само собой, у вас разделитель другой. Замените в коде `$arr = explode('»', $ybc);` на `$arr = explode('/', $ybc);`

Comment: да уже заменил, после замены крошки пропадают вовсе

Comment: и еще вопрос ваш код не позволит вывести крошки в таком формате http://joxi.ru/E2ppWkBUR3lo2Y т.к. жестко прописано что выводить, как то можно это поправить? Может задать функцию выводить все кроме?

Comment: Мой код получает крошки в строку, а дальше с ней можно делать что угодно, хоть финтифлюшки лепить со всех сторон. Это уже банальное php программирование.

Comment: с php пока только разбираюсь, поэтому могу и глупости спрашивать. Но тем немение $arr = explode('/', $ybc); так почему то не работает, крошки полностью пропадают

Comment: Я не знаю, какие ошибки вы делаете в коде, который я вам дал. У меня работает, и вы это видите. Вот ссылка на страницу, где все это реально работает: http://test.kagg.eu/product/%D1%84%D0%B8%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BC-%E2%84%962/    Я ответил на ваш вопрос.

Comment: у меня тоже работает, если все делать как в оригинале, так же как у вас, но если заменить в коде $arr = explode('»', $ybc); на $arr = explode('/', $ybc); как вы советуете, то крошки пропадают, попробуйте пожалуйста у себя.

Comment: У меня разделитель » в крошках, потому он в коде. Зачем мне ставить '/' ?

Comment: Еще раз: я ответил на ваш вопрос. В вопросе не было ни удаления части крошек, ни каких-то '/'. Так мы можем продолжать бесконечно программировать ваш сайт. Если у вас есть затруднения в применении работающего кода к вашему сайту, то следует обратиться к фрилансерам.

Comment: что бы посмотреть что код перестает работать. просто мне как раз нужен разделитель  '/'  , а с ним получается код не рабочий, жаль.

Comment: Если ответ полезен, его стоит отметить как принятый зеленой галочкой внизу. Это поможет ориентироваться пользователям, которые ищут ответ на подобный вопрос.

Comment: Подскажите, а что нужно прописать и изменить, чтобы придать хлебным крошкам другой вид на страницах атрибуты и метки?
В данный момент:
Метка: Главная / Товары с меткой “Название метки”
Атрибут: Главная / Товар Наименование атрибута / Имя атрибута
Нужно:
Метка: Главная / Название метки
Атрибут: Главная / Наименование атрибута / Имя атрибута Ну и в идеале, в URL убрать product-tag:
Название сайта/Название метки