# Исключить из вывода массива один элемент

Tags: php

Есть такой код где из вывода исключен элемент » Товары »
Пример 1

```
 if ( function_exists('yoast_breadcrumb') ) {
        $ybc = yoast_breadcrumb('','', false);
        $arr = explode('»', $ybc);
        $ybc = $arr[0] . '»' . $arr[2];
        echo $ybc;
    }
```

если добавить элементов

```
 if ( function_exists('yoast_breadcrumb') ) {
        $ybc = yoast_breadcrumb('','', false);
        $arr = explode('»', $ybc);
        $ybc = $arr[0] . '»' . $arr[2]. '»' . $arr[3]. '»' . $arr[4]. '»' . $arr[5];
        echo $ybc;
    }
```

то получим правильный вывод, Пример 2

но если элементов меньше, то результат не очень. Получаются значения пустые, а разделители есть. Пример 3

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Собственно вопрос в том как можно исключить один элемент из вывода, когда заранее не известно сколько может быть этих элементов.

Comment: Используйте циклы для вывода элементов из массива http://php.net/manual/ru/control-structures.for.php http://php.net/manual/ru/control-structures.foreach.php http://php.net/manual/ru/control-structures.while.php

Comment: С php только разбираюсь, поэтому пробую, но пока не получается

Comment: Так все-таки разделитель `»`, а не `/`, как вы говорили тут: http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/647496/%d0%9d%d0%b0%d1%81%d1%82%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b9%d0%ba%d0%b0-%d1%85%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%b1%d0%bd%d1%8b%d1%85-%d0%ba%d1%80%d0%be%d1%88%d0%b5%d0%ba-woocommerce/647523#comment924169_647523

Comment: вообще мне нужен разделитель /  код приведен для примера, данный вопрос не касается разделителя

Comment: KAGG Design  вам кстати большое спасибо и за такую помощь, но мне нужно немного другое, поэтому пытаюсь как то переделать код, что бы получить то что надо

Comment: @user242682 со / надо несколько иначе делать, строка же содержит теги внутри себя

Comment: кстати если в вашем коде в этой строке заменить символ то работает 
    $ybc = $arr[0] . '/' . $arr[2];

Comment: работает на тесте, но на реальной строке $ybc, которая содержит внутри себя теги, работать не может

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Чтобы использовать любой разделитель, нужно выделять его вместе с пробелами:

```
if ( function_exists('yoast_breadcrumb') ) {
    $ybc = yoast_breadcrumb('<p id="breadcrumbs">','</p>', false);
    $delim = ' » ';
    $arr = explode($delim, $ybc);
    $ybc = trim($arr[0]);
    for ($i = 2; $i < count($arr); $i++) {
        $ybc = $ybc . $delim . trim($arr[$i]);
    }

    echo $ybc;
}
```

В этом примере можно заменить `' » '` на `' / '` и код будет работать, потому что внутри тегов нет символов `'/'` с пробелами.

Comment: !Спасибо тебе мил человек))  только при таком значении $i+2 выводит немного не правильно, пропуская значения через одно. Если заменить на $i+1 все вроде работает как надо

Comment: да, в самом деле... исправил

Comment: так правильней $i++ чем $i+1 В любом случае ответ отмечен, респект вам.